# Prove the inequality $\sqrt{\frac{x}{y^2+z^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{y}{z^2+x^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{z}{x^2+y^2}}\ge \frac{2\sqrt{6}}3$ with $x+y+z=3,x,y,z\ge 0$

Tags: inequality, radicals, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality

> Let $x\geq0$, $y\geq0$ and $z\ge 0$ such that $x+y+z=3$. Show that
>   $$\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{y^2+z^2}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{y}{z^2+x^2}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{z}{x^2+y^2}}\ge \dfrac{2\sqrt{6}}{3}.$$

I tried C-S,Holder  but without success.
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{y^2+z^2}}\right)^2(\sum x(y^2+z^2))\ge (x+y+z)^3$$

Comment: I notice that the minimum and equality occurs for (x, y, z) = (3/2, 3/2, 0) (and permutations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Holder helps!
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{x}{y^2+z^2}}\right)^2\sum_{cyc}x^2(y^2+z^2)\geq(x+y+z)^3.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$(x+y+z)^3\geq\frac{8}{3}\sum_{cyc}x^2(y^2+z^2)$$ or
$$(x+y+z)^4\geq16\sum_{cyc}x^2y^2,$$ which is true by AM-GM:
$$(x+y+z)^4=\left(\sum_{cyc}(x^2+2xy)\right)^2\geq\left(2\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}x^2\cdot2\sum_{cyc}xy}\right)^2=$$
$$=8\sum_{cyc}(x^3y+x^3z+x^2yz)\geq8\sum_{cyc}(2x^2y^2)=16\sum_{cyc}x^2y^2.$$
Done!

Another way.

By AM-GM and C-S we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{x}{y^2+z^2}}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt6x}{2\sqrt{1.5x(y^2+z^2)}}\geq$$
$$\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt6x}{1.5x+y^2+z^2}=2\sqrt6\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{3x^2+2xy^2+2xz^2}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{2\sqrt6(x+y+z)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(3x^2+2x^2y+2x^2z)}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$3(x+y+z)^2\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}(3x^2+2x^2y+2x^2z)$$ or
$$3(xy+xz+yz)\geq\sum_{cyc}(x^2y+x^2z)$$ or
$$(x+y+z)(xy+xz+yz)\geq\sum_{cyc}(x^2y+x^2z)$$ or
$$3xyz\geq0.$$
Done againe!

Comment: Hello Michael sir, A wonderful solution !! Greetings !!( you probably can recognize me from AoPS) . Anyways I was wondering if convexiy/concavity could be of any help.

Comment: @adityaguharoy I tried convexity for $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, but it does not work I think.

Comment: Oh !! I thought the same function and thought it would work, but unfortunately it doesn't work !! Thank you for pointing out sir !!